# Resize static array in C

Tags: c, arrays, static, resize

UPDATE:
I've changed the static array for a dynamic, but I still get the segment violation error, although eclipse says:

```
*** glibc detected *** (path to file) double free or corruption (!prev): 0x00000000004093d0 ***
```

StructHashTable is a typedef...

```
int main() {
   ...
   StructHashTable *B0 = (StructHashTable *) malloc(N_ELEMS*sizeof(StructHashTable));
   ...
}

void resizeHash(StructHashTable *hash) {
    int size = currentElements + N_ELEMS;
    StructHashTable newHash[size];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) newHash[i].key = FREE;

    for (i = 0; i < currentElements; i++) insertHash(newHash, hash[i]);

    currentElements = size;

    hash = (StructHashTable *) realloc(hash, size*sizeof(StructHashTable));
    if (hash != NULL) {
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++) hash[i] = newHash[i];
    }
}
```

What's wrong now? Am I using in a bad way realloc? or what? C is driving me crazy...

OLD:
I'm working in university homework and I need to resize an static array in C, it has to be static, the debbugger says segment violation...

I have a main function that declares the array...

```
 // File: main.c
    int main() {
       ...
       StructHashTable hash[N_ELEMS];
       ...
    }
```

At some point on runtime I need more elements than N_ELEMS and I've written a function to do it in HashTable.c, that's the method:

```
 // File: HashTable.c
    #define N_ELEMS 32
    int currentElements = N_ELEMS

    void resizeHashTable(StructHashTable *hash) {
        int size = currentElements + N_ELEMS;
        StructHashTable newHash[size];
        int i;
        // Inicialize newHash
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++) newHash[i].key = FREE;

        // Insert old hash elements to the new table...
        for (i = 0; i < currentElements; i++) {
            insertHash(newHash, hash[i]);
        }

        currentElements = size;
        // I've tried making hash null with no luck...
        //hash = NULL;
        //free(hash);
        // HERE'S THE ERROR...
        hash = newHash;
        // I've tried *hash = *newHash with the same result...

    }
```

Can someone tell me how to do what I'm trying to do?

Thanks.

Comment: There is no way to resize a statically-allocated array. Your homework probably does not say that.

Comment: Maybe a design problem? cause homework says that clearly...

Comment: If your homework is written in English, consider posting that part in your answer or in a comment. *There is no way to resize an allocation.* The only thing you can do is to copy what you already have in newly-allocated memory and free the old allocation; but that means you need dynamic allocations.

Comment: What homework exactly say is: records are stored using a key-dependant hash table, with an initial size of the table of 32 elements,
to be expanded accordingly when filled.

Comment: So, it doesn't say anything about static arrays. Only thing that You must choose initial array size, which easily can be done with dynamic ones. Implementing hash table as a static array restrains You from increasing it's initial size. Solution would be changing static array to dynamic one.

Comment: You would need to use `malloc` to create the hash entries and `realloc` to increase the array size. You also need to pass the size of the hash table along.

Comment: Ok, if there's no other way of doing that, I suppose you're right, I'll try with malloc and realloc. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting error because you are trying to modify the l-value for a statically allocated array 'hash'.
Whenever you define an array (as in main)

```
StructHashTable hash[N_ELEMS];
```

sizeof(StructHashTable)*N_ELEMS bytes of memory is allocated for hash, and hash points to the first byte. Such an allocation is called static allocation and you cannot make hash point to some other memory allocation. It will give error as you specified, because the l-value i.e left hand side value cannot be modified. Neither you can free the memory assigned to hash. Memory assigned to hash will be freed only when main will terminate.

```
// HERE'S THE ERROR...
    hash = newHash;
```

I suggest you to use dynamic memory allocation for hash in main, if you wish to resize hash during run time.

```
int main() {
...
//Initial hash table creation
StructHashTable *B0 = (StructHashTable *) malloc(N_ELEMS*sizeof(StructHashTable));
...

...
//Do something
...

...
//hash table full. So resize hash table. This function call need not be inside main. Just for illustration purpose I am doing it here.
B0 = resizeHash(B0);
... 
}
```

And here's your modified resizeHash function.

```
StructHashTable* resizeHash(StructHashTable *oldHash) {

int size = currentElements + N_ELEMS;
int i; 

//Allocate memory for newHash with larger number of elements.
StructHashTable *newHash = (StructHashTable*) malloc(size * sizeof(StructHashTable));

if (newHash != NULL) {
    for (i = 0; i < currentElements; i++) {
    // Copy one by one oldHash table elements into newhash table
    //Something like below, or whatever you have been doing before to copy.
    newHash[i] = oldHash[i];        
    }
}   

//Free memory occupied by oldHash
free(oldHash);
//Set new value for currentElements 
currentElements = size;

//return the newHash address to calling function.   
return (newHash);   

}
```

Comment: Ok, I've done it but still get the error, I've updated the post with the new code...Thanks anyway.

Comment: Your usages of free and realloc is causing problem. See the code I have posted above for better understanding.